# InputMethodManager How to set the input method type ？

Tags: java, android

In Android, the inputmethodmanagerapi to manage the input method, and now has a problem, how to control the input method by the inputmethodmanager type, such as digital keyboard or letter keyboard, etc.?

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
List<InputMethodInfo> enabledInputMethodList = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
imm.setInputMethod(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), enabledInputMethodList.get(1).getId());
imm.setCurrentInputMethodSubtype(imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype());

imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

This can only call the Android system keyboard, but the keyboard type can not be controlled, for example: numeric keypad or letter keyboard.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this? All of the answers here are replying to use references to an EditText field which you will not have and are therefore not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply it to your object. For example, if you have an `EditText` object called `myEditText`, you can apply it and input type with `myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)`. When the user will click on your `EditText`, he will be prompted a keypad of type `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`

Comment: If not through EditText object, you can set the keyboard type by InputMethodManager?

Comment: I don't understand your goal. Do you want to set the input method to your entire app?

Comment: I want to set using the InputMethodManager sets the input type rather than EditText, through the InputMethodManager call the keyboard default letter type keyboard, but I want to set to numeric types by InputMethodManager keyboard

Answer (score 0):

In your EditText in xml file, add  following tag:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

and to be more specific about the choice, if you want, you can add this in xml:

```
              android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345679"
```

Comment: I think only through the InputMethodManager management sets the input type? Instead of using XML and EditText to set the type

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

by using xml,

```
android:inputType="WHAT_YOU_WANT"
```

[Click here](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AinputType)  to see possible types.

by using java,

```
YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_NAME.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
```

Comment: Now don't want to type by XML and EditText control keyboard

Comment: Can be controlled by InputMethodManager keyboard type? Providing API

Comment: what you mean by your question ,How to set the input method type ？actually what is your goal

Comment: I want to set using the InputMethodManager sets the input type rather than EditText, through the InputMethodManager call the keyboard default letter type keyboard, but I want to set to numeric types by InputMethodManager keyboard

Comment: android:inputType="number" - it's also give the solution for your requirement.

Comment: Set the input type can be managed through the InputMethodManager?

Comment: You can set the keyboard type by InputMethodManager? Is this all right? Are not in the XML settings.

Comment: this works only on a specific edit text. we're talking about changing the input type on the keyboard, not the edit text.